# Cut part of the string from longer string

Tags: snowflake-cloud-data-platform

I'm weak with this so I need help.

I need to cut part of the string from longer string.
I can't point it to position because it's always in different positions.

So I need to tell (regex?) that I need everything after this and until this occurs.

For example:

123aass|this=that&uuhh23ude23ddassa|aswwd=wfewe|as33=
35tscef433|this=that&ewwef3434[r2r23|2r3r23r?23r23r23r

I need to retrieve only "that"
SO I need to tell regex to start after "this=" and end at "&"
Or get me everything between "this=" and "&"

I'm not very good with this so please help.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Could you try this one?

```
select REGEXP_SUBSTR( mydata, '.*this=(.*)&.*', 1,1,'e') from values
('123aass|this=that&uuhh23ude23ddassa|aswwd=wfewe|as33='),
('35tscef433|this=that&ewwef3434[r2r23|2r3r23r?23r23r23r') tmp(mydata);
```